# tooltip div being cut in a list ul with overflow

Tags: html, css, tooltip, overflow

I have a side list that displays a tooltip with css only, the list is large, need to use overflow scroll, however when enable overflow the tooltip cut off by the parent div. Could someone help me how to solve this?

```css
*{padding:0px;margin:0px;}
html, body{background:#000;overflow:hidden;}
.painel
{
    width:15%;
    position:absolute;
    right:0px;
    top:80px;
    bottom:0px;
    overflow: auto;
    min-width:200px;
    background: blue;
}

#users_online ul{list-style-type:none;}
#users_online
{
    /*overflow: auto;*/
    padding-left:5px;
    background: red;
}
#users_online ul li
{
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    border:1px solid transparent;
    padding:0px;
    margin-left:-1px;
    border-right:0;
    position:relative;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
#users_online ul li:hover{border-color:#999; background:linear-gradient(to right, #FFF, #000 160%);}
#users_online ul li a{text-decoration:none; float:left; width:70%; margin-left:10px;font-size:14px;color:#999;line-height:40px;}
#users_online ul li a .name_title{line-height:20px;}
#users_online ul li a .name_data{font-size:12px;line-height:20px;}
#users_online ul li a p span.type_user{font-size:12px;text-transform:capitalize;font-weight:bold;}
#users_online ul li a:hover{color:#000;}

.imgSmall
{
    float:left;
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    overflow:hidden;
    border-radius:50%;
}
.imgSmall img{width:100%; height:100%;}

.tooltip_user
{
    position:absolute;
}
a.tooltip_user span.toolinfo:hover{text-decoration:none;color:rgb(139,29,30);}
a.tooltip_user span.toolinfo{font-size:14px;display:none;padding:10px 10px;margin-top:-40px;margin-left:-350px;width:310px;line-height:15px;}
a.tooltip_user:hover span.toolinfo{display:inline;position:absolute;border:1px solid #000;background:#CCC;color:#000;z-index:1;}
```

```html
<div class="painel"> 
    <aside id="users_online">
        <ul>
            <?php for($i=1; $i<=20; $i++): ?>
            <li id="<?php echo $i ?>">
                <div class="imgSmall"><img src="pictures/" border="0" /></div>
                <a href="#" class="tooltip_user">     
                    <p class="name_title">Name User Test</p><p class="name_data"><span class="type_user">User</span>/<span class="sec_user">Admin</span></p>

                    <span class="toolinfo">
                        <div style="float:left; width:80px; padding-right: 10px;"><img src="pictures/" border="0" width="80" height="80" style="border-radius:50%;"/></div>
                        <div style="float:right; width:220px;">
                            <p><strong>Name Test</strong></p>
                            <p><strong>User</strong></p>
                            <p>Admin</p>
                            <p><i>email@mail.com</i></p>
                            <br/>
                            <p style="font-size: 12px;">Last view online as 12:12 de 12/12/2012</p>
                        </div>
                    </span>
                </a>
                <span class="status off"></span>
            </li>
            <?php endfor; ?>
        </ul>
    </aside>
</div>
```